# Python - prevent "for i in range:" cutting off end of sequence

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on a program to analyse protein amino acid content(specifically areas very rich in G/L content).

I am splitting up sequences of varying lengths into "chunks" of 20aa using:

```
seq = 'MVFRSPLDLYSSHFLLPNFADSHHCSLLLASSGGGSGASGGGGGAGGGGGGNRAGGGGAGGAGGGSGGGGSRAPPEELSMFQLPTLNFSPEQVASVCETLEETGDIERLGRFLWSLPVAPGACEAINKHESILRARAVVAFHTGNFRDLYHILENHKFTKESHGKLQAMWLEAHYQEAEKLRGRPLGPVDKYRVRKKFPLPRTIWDGEQKTHCFKERTRSLLREWYLQDPYPNPSKKRELAQATGLTPTQVGNWFKNRRQRDRAAAAKNRLQHQAIGPSGMRSLAEPGCPTHGSAESPSTAASPTTSVSSLTERADTGTSILSVTSSDSECDV'
w = 20 #chunk size
interval = 20
for i in range(0,len(seq)-w,interval):
   chunk = seq[i:i+w]
   chunk2 = list(chunk)
```

However this cuts of the end of the sequence if it is not a multiple of 20 like in this case len(seq) = 333

This gives me 1-320 as chunks but 321-333 are ignored. How can I get these "leftovers" into a list?

Comment: Drop the `-w` in your `range`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make your existing code work if you take out the `-w` from your `range` call. Slicing off the end of a sequence is perfectly legal, it just returns a shorter result than you asked for.

If you want to have a dummy value to fill in the missing parts for the last piece of the sequence (rather than the last parts just being missing), you can use the `grouper` recipe from [the `itertools` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```